# Exporting from org-mode to HTML: how to include reference using bibtex

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use org-mode to write posts, and sometimes I want to include reference in the post using my general .bib file with all my references. I know how to export to latex, but when I try to export the same file to html, the reference does not appear in the page. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use org-ref for this: https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref It defines cite and bibliography links that export to LaTeX, and with decent HTML export.

(update: fixed link)

Comment: The link is dead but here's some lead: http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2014/05/13/Using-org-ref-for-citations-and-references/ .

Comment: The right link is https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref. It is available on Melpa for easy install too.